# How to access content of: <open file 'my_file', mode 'r' at 0x122db1780>

Tags: python, object

I have obtained a saved file from a script and I want to read/display its content (gravity values).

I have opened the file using

```
with open('station_values', "r") as f:
    print f
```

which prints:

```
<open file 'my_file', mode 'r' at 0x122db1780>
```

`print f.read()` doesn't print anything. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `f.seek(0)` before doing `f.read()`?

Comment: `print f.read()` doesnt' print anything at all? And you're sure the file contains text?

Comment: Two possibilities: Your file is empty, or you have already read everything from the file and the file position is at the end (in which case a `f.seek(0)` would return you to the start).

Comment: Or, a third possibility: your file contains only whitespace or other characters that your terminal doesn't actually display. You could try `print repr(f.read())` instead. If that prints `''` you still have one of the two earlier possibilities I mentioned. Or it prints `'\t\n'` and then you know you have a tab and a newline in the file.

Comment: `print repr(f.read())` returns `\x80\x02}q\x00(U\x08tilt_stdq\x01]q\x02(cnumpy.core.multiarray\nscalar\nq\x03cnumpy\ndtype\nq\x04U\ `  followed by a lot of  `\x03h\x07U\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00q7 ` type code. and `f.seek(0)` returns `None`. What can I do with this info?

Comment: do `with open('station_values', "rb") as f:`

Comment: good suggestion. I tried. `with open('station_values', "rb") as f:`
 `print f.seek(0)`
 `print f.read()` this returns again `None`

Comment: Are you really sure the file has content that isn't being written when you are trying to read it?

Comment: I think so. The file is a placed on my desktop and the script consists of 4 lines. couldn't possibly imagine that it is being written while trying I am trying to read it.

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
 with open('station_values') as f:
  print f.readlines()
```